# R to tableau: why R some r codes connected to Tableau returning an error?

Tags: r, tableau-desktop, forecast

I have been able to connect R to Tableau and executed an ARIMA forecast without an issue.

In that same way, I tried to execute ETS and nnetar forecasting on the same data without much success.

The codes work perfectly in R as follows.

```
    SCRIPT_REAL("
library(forecast)
library(imputeTS)
library(urca)
library(vars)
library(mFilter)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)
library(TSstudio)
library(TSPred)
library(fpp2)
library(TSA)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
ts.data<-.arg1
ts.data<-ts(ts.data,frequency=21, start=c(2020,2))
fit<-ets(ts.data)
forecasted<-forecast(fit,h=22)
n<-length(.arg1)
append(.arg1[(22+1):n],forecasted$mean, n-22)
",SUM([Court Services Victoria]))
```

Trying to execute this in Tableau returns the following error
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension data source 'Analytics Extension'

```
Error Code:6116DD27
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension.
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension.
Error in UseMethod("forecast") : 
  no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "ets"
```

The code works in R studio.

Another code that does not work in Tableau but works in R is as below
SCRIPT_REAL("

```
ts.data<-.arg1
ts.data<-ts(ts.data,frequency=21, start=c(2020,2))
fit<-nnetar(ts.data)
forecasted<-forecast(fit,h=22)
n<-length(.arg1)
append(.arg1[(22+1):n],forecasted$mean, n-22)
",SUM([Court Services Victoria]))

Returns the following error
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension.
An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension. Error in UseMethod("forecast") : no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "nnetar"
```

I have never had an issue with auto.arima and forecasting the series.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's `.arg1` ? It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Given the errors I'd check for a package issue. You can clean up your library calls and test again. I think your script only needs library(forecast). Note that you have three forecast calls in your script, two library calls and one in fpp2. You may also need tseries, urca, and zoo, which are imported by forecast. There is a link to Rcpp, and a common fix for package errors is to reinstall Rcpp. You can test where tableau is getting forecast from with `find.package("forecast")` and check your install for issues by looking for warnings or errors when you run `library(forecast)`.

Comment: You can check which version of forecast you have with `packageVersion("forecast")`. Current is 8.18. Your R version should be at least 3.5. You can check with `R.version`.